# iOS 17 Beta Shared AVAudioPlayer State Between App and Widget

Tags: swift, widget, avaudioplayer, ios17

I'm working on creating an audio playback widget for my app, aiming for functionality similar to the Apple Music widget. Specifically, I've implemented a play button in my widget that triggers an AudioPlaybackIntent. This intent then interacts with a singleton class that manages my AVAudioPlayer.

The issue I'm facing is that the AVAudioPlayer instance in my main app and the instance in my widget extension don't seem to share the same state.

I've noticed that the Apple Music widget is capable of showing real-time changes, which implies that it has some way of sharing the playback state between the main app and the widget.

How can I achieve shared state between the main app and widget for my AVAudioPlayer instance?
Is there a specific approach or API that Apple Music uses to make this happen?

Here's my code flow:

```swift
struct PlayBalanceTrackIntent: AudioPlaybackIntent {
    init() {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to set up audio session category: \(error)")
        }
    }

    init(trackURL: String) {
        self.trackURL = trackURL
    }

    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        if PlayerModel.shared.isPlaying {
            PlayerModel.shared.pauseAudio()
        } else {
            PlayerModel.shared.setupAudio(from: trackURL)
        }
        return .result()
    }
}
```

then there's simple player

```swift
class PlayerModel: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = PlayerModel()
    @Published var mainPlayer: AVPlayer?
    @Published var isPlaying: Bool = false

    private var timeObserver: Any?

    private init() {
        setupCommandCenter()
    }

    deinit {
        if let timeObserver = timeObserver {
            mainPlayer?.removeTimeObserver(timeObserver)
        }
    }

    private func setupCommandCenter() {
        let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

        commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] _ in
            self.playAudio()
            return .success
        }

        commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] _ in
            self.pauseAudio()
            return .success
        }
    }

    func setupAudio(from url: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }

        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
        mainPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

        timeObserver = mainPlayer?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTime(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: 1), queue: .main) { [weak self] time in
            let currentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(time)
            self?.time = self?.formatTime(time: currentTime) ?? "00:00"
            self?.updateNowPlayingInfo()
        }

        playAudio()
    }

    func playAudio() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.mainPlayer?.play()
            self.isPlaying = true
            self.updateNowPlayingInfo()
        }
    }

    func pauseAudio() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.mainPlayer?.pause()
            self.isPlaying = false
        }
    }

    private func updateNowPlayingInfo() {
        let currentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(mainPlayer?.currentTime() ?? CMTime.zero)
        time = formatTime(time: currentTime)

        var nowPlayingInfo = [String: Any]()
        nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] = "Your Title"
        nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = currentTime
        nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] = CMTimeGetSeconds(mainPlayer?.currentItem?.duration ?? CMTime.zero)
        nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = mainPlayer?.rate ?? 0.0
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
    }
```

Comment: Nobody here can tell you what Apple uses but if you share an example we might be able to help you solve your issue.

Comment: I have added some code to maybe make it clearer.